# Node JS Load JSON array from file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

a json file has been created with pretty print like that

```
[
  {
    "name": "c",
    "content": 3,
    "_prototype": "item"
  },
  {
    "name": "d",
    "content": 4,
    "_prototype": "item"
  }
]
```

I can read the file with that

```
var fs = require('fs');
var arrayPath = './array.json';

function fsReadFileSynchToArray (filePath) {
    var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath));
    console.log(data);
    return data;
}

var test  = arr.loadFile(arrayPath);
console.log(test);
```

but the output is in reverse order

```
[]
[ { name: 'c', content: 3, _prototype: 'item' },
  { name: 'd', content: 4, _prototype: 'item' },]
```

obviously the second output is shown as first. I used actually synchronous file read to avoid such an empty data stuff. Is there a way to really make sure the JSON file is completely read into an array before continuing ?

[update]
arr is a module which uses

```
function loadFile(filePath){
    var arrLines = [];
    fs.stat(filePath, function(err, stat) {
        if(err == null) {
            arrLines = fsReadFileSynchToArray(filePath);
        } else if(err.code == 'ENOENT') {
            console.log('error: loading file ' + filePath + ' not found');
        } else {
            console.log('error: loading file', err.code);
        }
    });
    return arrLines;
}
```

to return the values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: no it's a sychronous call not an asynchronous

Comment: Not according to the output you are getting.

Comment: @vlaz — There's no callback function anywhere. `readFileSync` is not asyncronous.

Comment: I don't understand how either of the `console.log()` calls outputs an empty array. Nor do I understand how one of them has a trailing comma after the last object in it.

Comment: it clearly uses fs.readFileSync . see Node tutorials abut the two are completetly different

Comment: `arr.loadFile` — What is `arr`? You don't define it anywhere. Your code won't compile, you need a real [MCVE]

Comment: FYI, you can just `require` JSON.

Comment: Where are you even calling `fsReadFileSynchToArray` from?

Comment: added some update to explain that

Comment: @Ben never heard of it, do you have an example ?

Comment: @user3732793 Yes you have, you're using it in your code. Just not for JSON. `var objOrArray = require('./path/to/file.json');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fs.stat` is async, so your function is async.

You want [`fs.fstatSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_fstatsync_fd) instead.

Answer (score 28):

As long as the file is inside your project folder (config file, i.e.) you can load it synchronously requiring it directly in NodeJS.

```
var test = require('./array.json');
```

And then the content will be loaded into your variable in the next executed sentence.

You can try to console.log it, and it will print:

```
[ { name: 'c', content: '3', _prototype: 'item' },
  { name: 'd', content: '4', _prototype: 'item' } ]
```

Right exactly in the order that the file had.

Comment: that did work nicely thanks. Thought that is what Ben mentioned

Answer (score 5):

Testing if a file exists before loading is not recommended and is the reason why [`fs.exists`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) is deprecated:

> Using `fs.exists()` to check for the existence of a file before calling `fs.open()`, `fs.readFile()` or `fs.writeFile()` is not recommended. Doing so introduces a race condition, since other processes may change the file's state between the two calls. Instead, user code should open/read/write the file directly and handle the error raised if the file does not exist.

And the way you use `fs.stats` is just an equivalent to the deprecated `fs.exists`.

So you should always assume that the file does not exits when reading it.

For a sync call you should write:

```
var data;

try {
   data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath));
} catch ( err ) {
   // handle your file not found (or other error) here
}
```

or

```
var data;

try {
   data = require('./array.json');
} catch ( err ) {
   // handle your file not found (or other error) here
}
```

And if you do it the async way then check the error argument of your callback function, to handle the case if the file does not exist:

```
fs.readFile(filePath, (err, fileContent) => {
    var data;
    if( err ) {
      // handle your file not found (or other error) here
    } else {
      data = JSON.parse(fileContent);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

```
const fs=require('fs');
var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('file.json', 'utf8'));
console.log(obj);
```